# Entity Framework TPH Inheritance errors:

Tags: entity-framework

I get the error message;
error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 77:Condition member 'Company.CompanyTypeId' with a condition other than 'IsNull=False' is mapped. Either remove the condition on Company.CompanyTypeId or remove it from the mapping.

I have done a search on how to fix, this but I do not understand the answers.

My classes are

```
public abstract class Company
    {
        public Company()
        {
            this.AddressLines = new List<AddressLine>();
        }

        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public int CompanyTypeId { get; set; }

        public string Comments { get; set; }

        public DateTime? EndOfBusinessDate { get; set; }


        public virtual CompanyType CompanyType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Subcontractor : Company
    {
        public Subcontractor()
        {
            this.SubcontractorTrades = new List<SubcontractorTrade>();
        }

        public virtual ICollection<SubcontractorTrade> SubcontractorTrades { get; set; }
        public string ValueOfWork { get; set; }
        public string QualityAssured { get; set; }
        public int? NumberOfOperatives { get; set; }


        public static IPagedList<Subcontractor> GetSubcontractors(int page, int PageSize)
        {
            using (var db = new SherryGreenGroupContext())
            {
                return db.Subcontractors
                    .Include("SubcontractorTrades")
                    .Include("AddressLines")
                    .Where(x => x.EndOfBusinessDate == null)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Company1)
                    .ToPagedList(page, PageSize);
            }
        }
    }
```

My mappings look like;

```
   public CompanyMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.CompanyId);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Comments).HasMaxLength(1023);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Company");
        this.Property(t => t.CompanyId).HasColumnName("CompanyId");

        this.Property(t => t.CompanyTypeId).HasColumnName("CompanyTypeId");
        this.Property(t => t.Comments).HasColumnName("Comments");
        this.Property(t => t.Created).HasColumnName("Created");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.CompanyType).WithMany(t => t.Companies).HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyTypeId);
    }
}

public class SubcontractorMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Subcontractor>
{
    public SubcontractorMap()
    {
        this.Property(t => t.QualityAssured).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(1);
        this.Property(t => t.ValueOfWork).HasMaxLength(255);

        this.Property(t => t.QualityAssured).HasColumnName("QualityAssured");
        this.Property(t => t.ValueOfWork).HasColumnName("ValueOfWork");
        this.Property(t => t.NumberOfOperatives).HasColumnName("NumberOfOperatives");
    }
}
```

The context class looks like

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CompanyMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SubcontractorMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SupplierMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ArchitectsAndSurveyorMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StructuralEngineerMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CostConsultantMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ServiceEngineerMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CompanyTypeMap());
                    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .Map<Subcontractor>(m => m.Requires("CompanyTypeId").HasValue(4))
            .Map<Supplier>(m => m.Requires("CompanyTypeId").HasValue(5))
            .Map<ArchitectsAndSurveyor>(m => m.Requires("CompanyTypeId").HasValue(1))
            .Map<StructuralEngineer>(m => m.Requires("CompanyTypeId").HasValue(2))
            .Map<CostConsultant>(m => m.Requires("CompanyTypeId").HasValue(3))
            .Map<ServiceEngineer>(m => m.Requires("CompanyTypeId").HasValue(6));
    }
}
```

I have tried commentinout out CompanyTypeId from both the class definition and the mapping code, but I get the same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use CompanyTypeId as discriminator for TPH you must not use it for anything else => you cannot have it as property in `Company` class and you cannot have relation with `CompanyType` class. The reason is that entity type in inheritance is immutable. Changing either `CompanyTypeId` or `CompanyType` in `Company` class would change the type of the entity but you cannot change the type of existing instance.

Comment: The CompanyTypeId is on the company datatable. So how do I ignore this field when I query the database in the GetSubcontractors() query?

Comment: Yes it is in the table but your mapping already uses it to define Subcontractor as inherited type.

Comment: When I remove the CompanyTypeId from the Company class, I get a SQL exception; Invalid column name 'CompanyType_CompanyTypeId'.

Comment: You also have to remove relation with CompanyType table. That table is useless for your model if you want to use inheritance.

Comment: I haven't updated the database with these changes because although I am using Code First, I have reversed engineered it from an existing database.

Comment: Yes I remove the foriegn key constraint on the database and it worked. Thank you for that.